# Variable equality in Prolog applied to lists

Tags: prolog

Say you have a list like so:

```
[
  [[X],[X]],             %1
  [[Y],[Y]],             %2
  [[X],[Y]],             %3
  [[X,Y],[X,Y]],         %4
  [[X,Z],[X,Z]],         %5
  [[X,Y],[Y,X]],         %6
  [[X,Y],[X,Y],[X,Y],    %7
  [[X,Z],[X,Z],[X,Z],    %8
  [[X,Y],[X,Z],[Z,Y],    %9
]
```

I want to define an equality operator so that:

- elements 1 and 2 are considered equal, i.e. [[X],[X]] == [[Y],[Y]] is true
- elements 4 and 5 are considered equal, i.e. [[X,Y],[X,Y]] == [[X,Z],[X,Z]] is true
- elements 7 and 8 are considered equal, i.e. [[X,Y],[X,Y],[X,Y]] == [[X,Z],[X,Z],[X,Z] is true

Equality is defined in terms of the position of the variables, not the variables themselves.

So [[X],[X]] and [[Y],[Y]] are equal because the position of their variables are the same.

I want to use this equality operator to convert the list to a set. However, I am not sure how to define this equality.

I was thinking about replacing each variable with an indexed number like so:

```
[[X],[X]] = [[1],[1]]
[[Y],[Y]] = [[1],[1]]
[[X],[Y]] = [[1],[2]]
[[X,Y],[X,Y]] = [[1,2],[1,2]]
[[X,Z],[X,Z]] = [[1,2],[1,2]]
[[X,Y],[Y,Z]] = [[1,2],[2,1]],
[[X,Y],[X,Y],[X,Y] = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
[[X,Z],[X,Z],[X,Z] = [[1,2],[1,2],[1,2]]
[[X,Y],[X,Z],[Z,Y] = [[1,2],[1,3],[3,2]]
```

But this seems a bit 'hacky'

Can anyone help?

p.s.

This question might need a better title, I was unsure what to put.

Comment: What is your definition of two elements of the highest level list being equal? Is it that the first two of three elements match across the corresponding pairs of triplets? Could you give some examples of other lists with elements that are equal versus those that aren't? And is your question just that you want to know how to test two elements of the form `[[A,B,C],[D,E,F]]` for equality?

Comment: What do this lists of lists of lists of variables represent? Abusing lists is a well known code smell in Prolog programming.

Comment: So two elements are equal if (1) they have all the same subelements and (2) the subelements are in the same order, regardless of how they're broken up into the sublists?

Comment: @mbratch I have updated the question to try to make it more clear. Two elements are equal if the relative positions of their elements are the same.

Comment: @PauloMoura they represent higher-order meta-rules. So the list [P,X,Y] represents P(X,Y). I am trying to generate these meta-rules but I have duplicates, i.e. I have P(X,Y) and P(X,Z), which are the same.

Comment: Would `[[X],[Y]] == [[X],[Y]]`? Would `[[X,Y],[X,Z],[X,Z]] == [[X,W],[X,T],[X,T]]`? And when you say things like `X` and `Y`, being that these are variables, the equality checks are after they've been instantiated and `X` and `Y` represent variables with different instantiation?

Comment: @mbratch your examples are both true. The quality check are before instantiation. X and Y could be same. So [[X,Y],[X,Y]] where X = a and Y = b would be [[a,b][a,b]], but Y could also be 'a' so you would have [[a,a],[a,a]].

Comment: Is `[[X,Y],[X,Y]] == [[Z,W],[Z,W]]`? I'm supposing not, but not sure. They key to writing prolog logic for equality would be if you could express in words what equality means between two elements.

Comment: @mbratch [[X,Y],[X,Y]] is equal to [[Z,W],[Z,W]]. I think my idea of representing each variable as an indexed number will work. I just wondered if there was another solution.

Comment: Oh there may be another solution. I was just trying to sort out what equality really means.

Comment: This is not the clearest definition, but two lists are equal if:

1, they both have the contain same number of sublists.
2, for each sublist, both lists have the same length of sublist, i.e. the sublist at position i in list A is the same length as the sublist in position i in list B.
3, the relative position of each occurrence of each variable is the same in both lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the concept of *variant*, i.e. terms that are equal up to variable renaming.  Several Prologs have a builtin called `variant/2` (e.g. [SWI](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=terms%3avariant/2), [ECLiPSe](http://www.eclipseclp.org/doc/bips/kernel/termcomp/variant-2.html)).  The latest revision of ISO Prolog has subsumes_term/2 which can be used to define

```
variant(X,Y) :- subsumes_term(X,Y), subsumes_term(Y,X).
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure about how useful this will be, it's just an example that tries to apply a specialized comparison (eequ/2) to each pair...

```
t(Fe,Se) :- L = [
  [[P,X,Y],[Q,X,Y]],
  [[P,X,Z],[Q,X,Z]],
  [[P,X,Y],[Q,Y,X]]
],
    select(Fe, L, R),
    member(Se, R),
    eequ(Fe,Se).

eequ([F|L1],[F|L2]) :- maplist(==,L1,L2).
```

if course, it does duplicate the matching rows...

```
?- t(A,B).
A = B, B = [[_G2289, _G2292, _G2295], [_G2301, _G2292, _G2295]] ;
A = B, B = [[_G2289, _G2292, _G2295], [_G2301, _G2292, _G2295]] ;
false.
```